# How do I return an array containing the digits of the initial number

Tags: java, arrays, digits

Given a non-negative integer, I need to return an array containing the digits of the initial number, considering that the initial number shall be less than 100,000. 
For example:

```
separateDigits(93) → {9, 3}
separateDigits(125) → {1, 2, 5}
separateDigits(732) → {7, 3, 2}
```

How do I separate the digits?

Comment: Simply use `int digit = value % 10`

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with?  Do you know how to write a function, create an array, divide by 10?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array but first you need to know how big. Then you need to fill the array with digits.

```
public byte[] separateDigits(long n) {
    int digits = 1; 
    for(long m = n; (m /= 10) > 0; digits++);

    byte[] ret = new byte[digits];
    for(int i = digits - 1 ; i >= 0; i--, n /= 10)
        ret[i] = (byte) (n % 10);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Peter Lawrey, this is the method preset for this problem: public int[] separateDigits(int num) {

Comment: So I can't use byte [] or long n

Answer (score 0):

```
//this might help you

import java.util.*;
public class SeparaeDigits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num =123;
     seperateDigits(num);


    }
    public static void seperateDigits(int num){
        int i=0;
        int remainder =0;
        int []arr = new int[3];
while(num>0){
 remainder = num % 10;
num = num/10;
for(i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
    arr[i]=remainder;

}
for(i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
System.out.println(arr[i]);
}

}
}
}
```